# (Angular 6/7/8) Display angular bootstrap carousel navigation indicators like Instagram

Tags: angular, carousel, angular7, angular8

I'm using angular bootstrap's carousel to display my images. Does anyone know how I can display the navigation indicators' animation like the Instagram? I was hoping to get something like this: https://codepen.io/swarad07/pen/xmzQKm

The carousel's navigation indicators are hidden and only shown when the user reaches the dot towards the end of the line.

Appreciate your help!

**carousel.component.html**

```
<ngb-carousel [showNavigationArrows]="false"
   [showNavigationIndicators]="true" data-interval="false">
   <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let imageID of imageIDs">
      <img class="carousel-img" [src]="profile | profileImage: imageID" />
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template ngbSlide *ngIf="!imageIDs?.length">
      <img class="carousel-img" [src]="{} | profileImage" />
   </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

**carousel.component.scss**

```
.carousel-indicators {
  bottom: -35px !important;
  bottom: -35px;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 1px solid $color-text-light;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: $color-text-light;
}
```

Comment: but the dots will show according to no. of  images.So what's your question here

Comment: sorry I rephrased, I want the dots to be animated like the link I showed. For now if too many images are shown, the dots becomes vertical lines so I'm hoping to adopt Instagram's solution by animating the dots to show only when necessary